# Regexp to remove specific number of occurrences of character only

Tags: python, regex

In Python `re`, I have long strings of text with `>` character chunks of different lengths. One string can have 3 consecutive `>` chars in the middle, `>>` in the beginning, or any such combination.

I want to write a regexp that, after splitting the string based on spaces, iterates through each word to only identify those regions with exactly 2 occurrences `>>`, and I can't be sure if it's at the beginning, middle or end of the whole string, or what characters are before or after it, or if it's even the only 2 characters in the string.

So far I could come up with:

```
word = re.sub(r'>{2}', '', word)
```

This ends up removing all occurrences of 2 or more. What regular expression would work for this requirement? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure there is no character of your choice both on the left and right using a pair of [lookaround, a lookahead and a lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The general scheme is

```
(?<!X)X{n}(?!X)
```

where `(?<!X)` means *no `X` immediately on the left is allowed*, `X{n}` means *n occurrences of `X`*, and `(?!X)` means *no `X` immediately on the right is allowed*.

In this case, use

```
r'(?<!>)>{2}(?!>)'
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BdnRkP/1).

Answer (score 0):

no need to split on spaces first if dont needs to

try `(?<![^ ])[^ >]*>>[^ >]*(?![^ ])`

finds segments on space boundry's with only `>>` in it and no more